# Can not add DirectX library in my project reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to use this code in my tool

```
AviManager aviManager = new AviManager(txtAviFileName.Text, true);
AudioStream audioStream = aviManager.GetWaveStream();
audioStream.ExportStream( @"..\..\testdata\sound.wav" );
aviManager.Close();
```

You can find whole whole tutorial here:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library

Problem is that i can not Find AviManager Class anywhere. I tried to add AviFile.dll in my reference but it does not allow giving an error.

> A reference to avifile.dll could not be added. Please Make sure File
>   is accessible ...................

I searched it and it looks like it must be a part of DirectX library. Currently i have confirmed DirectX 11 is installed in my machine but i can not find any reference.